# Comparison of AOP tools for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aop

From an asp.net perspective (C#)
What are the strengths and weaknesses of each AOP tool?
Some factors to include:

- Learning curve (for AOP newbies)
- Interceptions possible
- Performance
- Cost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Understanding AOP in .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/03/28/understanding-aop-in-net.aspx)

Comment: I think PostSharp is the best .NET AOP tool, but it doesn't have an official support for ASP.NET Web Sites (but it does for ASP.NET Web Applications!): http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/On-PostSharp-Support-of-ASPNET-Web-Sites.aspx

Comment: The post mentions ObjectBuilder2 container, which has been consumed by Unity container with pretty powerful interception capabilities. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660891(PandP.20).aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could use [PostSharp4AspNet](http://postsharp4aspnet.codeplex.com/) but still they are don't recommend that unless you are using it in a web application (precompiled) not a web site.